# Best Practice: Select by id or class with jQuery?

Tags: dom, jquery-selectors

Assuming that every element in the DOM has its own unique class name:

1. Is it better practice to use IDs versus class names when selecting elements in the DOM with jQuery?
2. Are there any performance advantages when using one over the other in jQuery?

I've been told that traditionally getting a DOM element via ID instead of by class is much faster and usually better practice, but does that apply to jQuery as well?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using classes correctly if no two objects share a class?

Comment: I agree with sarnold, having unique class names is senselessly.

Comment: Well I am also using those classes for CSS purposes; not just for selecting.

Comment: in css you can use ids just as classes(#id{} instead of .class{})

Comment: @x2, I'm trying to stick to best-practice conventions. Is it better to use #id in my CSS code than to have both an ID and a class name on my elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery just leverages browser functionality. On older browsers(IE<9), there is no `getElementsByClassName` function, but virtually every browser supports `getElementById`. On these browsers, jQuery has to traverse the whole tree and look for all elements with the given classname. Therefore, using IDs will be faster.

However, bear in mind that id's must be unique, i.e. you can't have two elements with the same ID. This is often not advisable, since components may be used in different contexts on the same page. Using IDs exclusively would prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by ID is still faster than by class-names in jquery.